# Duplicate symbols from libm and libstdc++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, rust

I am having issues with using Rust and Bindgen with C++ to compile a Rust program that uses C++ libraries.

Compiling for target armv7r-none-eabi using Cargo, on 64 bit Ubuntu 18.04. I've tried using newlib instead of gcc-arm-embedded, but that didn't help, so I switched back.

Here is my build script:

```
#[allow(non_snake_case)]

extern crate bindgen;

use std::env;
use std::path::PathBuf;

fn main() {
    // Tell cargo to tell rustc to link the v5rt library
    // shared library
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=libraries/");
    //println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/7.3.1/");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=/usr/arm-none-eabi/lib");
    //println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=/usr/lib/arm-none-eabi/newlib/");


    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=v5rt");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=stdc++");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=c");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=m");
    //println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=gcc");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=supc++");

    // The bindgen::Builder is the main entry point
    // to bindgen, and lets you build up options for
    // the resulting bindings.
    let bindings = bindgen::Builder::default()

        // The input header we would like to generate
        // bindings for.
        .header("vex/include/v5.h")

        .clang_arg("-I'$(TOOLCHAIN)/$(PLATFORM)/include'")

        .use_core()

        .ctypes_prefix("cty")
        // Finish the builder and generate the bindings.
        .generate()
        // Unwrap the Result and panic on failure.
        .expect("Unable to generate bindings");

    // Write the bindings to the $OUT_DIR/bindings.rs file.
    let out_path = PathBuf::from(env::var("OUT_DIR").unwrap());
    bindings
        .write_to_file(out_path.join("bindings.rs"))
        .expect("Couldn't write bindings!");
}
```

I can't share the contents of v5.h, but it includes some std headers. This should be fine, since the errors make no mention of libv5rt.

The expected result of this is that I end up with a statically linked binary that calls C++ functions from within Rust, but instead, I get the following errors:

```
warning: unused manifest key: build
   Compiling Monolith v0.1.0 (/home/nottherootaccount/pRust/project)
error: linking with `rust-lld` failed: exit code: 1
  |
  = note: "rust-lld" "-flavor" "gnu" "-L" "/home/nottherootaccount/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/armv7r-none-eabi/lib" "/home/nottherootaccount/pRust/project/target/armv7r-none-eabi/debug/deps/Monolith-1f0e2a190ceafaf5.2g6qot1433lhmu8x.rcgu.o" "-o" "/home/nottherootaccount/pRust/project/target/armv7r-none-eabi/debug/deps/Monolith-1f0e2a190ceafaf5" "--gc-sections" "-L" "/home/nottherootaccount/pRust/project/target/armv7r-none-eabi/debug/deps" "-L" "/home/nottherootaccount/pRust/project/target/debug/deps" "-L" "libraries/" "-L" "/usr/arm-none-eabi/lib" "-L" "/home/nottherootaccount/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/armv7r-none-eabi/lib" "-Bstatic" "--whole-archive" "-lv5rt" "--no-whole-archive" "--whole-archive" "-lstdc++" "--no-whole-archive" "--whole-archive" "-lc" "--no-whole-archive" "--whole-archive" "-lm" "--no-whole-archive" "--whole-archive" "-lsupc++" "--no-whole-archive" "/home/nottherootaccount/pRust/project/target/armv7r-none-eabi/debug/deps/libcty-d94d348a8ecb57da.rlib" "/home/nottherootaccount/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/armv7r-none-eabi/lib/librustc_std_workspace_core-02da144480cd28a7.rlib" "/home/nottherootaccount/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/armv7r-none-eabi/lib/libcore-562f601a6298b539.rlib" "/home/nottherootaccount/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/armv7r-none-eabi/lib/libcompiler_builtins-2aa2db429e3347eb.rlib" "-Bdynamic"
  = note: rust-lld: error: duplicate symbol: __aeabi_atexit
          >>> defined at atexit_arm.cc
          >>>            atexit_arm.o:(__aeabi_atexit) in archive /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libstdc++.a
          >>> defined at aeabi_atexit.c
          >>>            lib_a-aeabi_atexit.o:(.text.__aeabi_atexit+0x0) in archive /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a

          rust-lld: error: duplicate symbol: acosl
          >>> defined at math_stubs_long_double.cc
          >>>            math_stubs_long_double.o:(acosl) in archive /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libstdc++.a
          >>> defined at acosl.c
          >>>            lib_a-acosl.o:(.text.acosl+0x0) in archive /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libm.a

          rust-lld: error: duplicate symbol: asinl
          >>> defined at math_stubs_long_double.cc
          >>>            math_stubs_long_double.o:(asinl) in archive /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libstdc++.a
          >>> defined at asinl.c
          >>>            lib_a-asinl.o:(.text.asinl+0x0) in archive /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libm.a

          rust-lld: error: duplicate symbol: atan2l
          >>> defined at math_stubs_long_double.cc
          >>>            math_stubs_long_double.o:(atan2l) in archive /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libstdc++.a
          >>> defined at atan2l.c
          >>>            lib_a-atan2l.o:(.text.atan2l+0x0) in archive /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libm.a

          rust-lld: error: duplicate symbol: atanl
          >>> defined at math_stubs_long_double.cc
          >>>            math_stubs_long_double.o:(atanl) in archive /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libstdc++.a
          >>> defined at atanl.c
          >>>            lib_a-atanl.o:(.text.atanl+0x0) in archive /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libm.a

          rust-lld: error: duplicate symbol: ceill
          >>> defined at math_stubs_long_double.cc
          >>>            math_stubs_long_double.o:(ceill) in archive /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libstdc++.a
          >>> defined at ceill.c
          >>>            lib_a-ceill.o:(.text.ceill+0x0) in archive /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libm.a

          rust-lld: error: duplicate symbol: coshl
          >>> defined at math_stubs_long_double.cc
          >>>            math_stubs_long_double.o:(coshl) in archive /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libstdc++.a
          >>> defined at coshl.c
          >>>            lib_a-coshl.o:(.text.coshl+0x0) in archive /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libm.a

          rust-lld: error: duplicate symbol: cosl
          >>> defined at math_stubs_long_double.cc
          >>>            math_stubs_long_double.o:(cosl) in archive /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libstdc++.a
          >>> defined at cosl.c
          >>>            lib_a-cosl.o:(.text.cosl+0x0) in archive /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libm.a

          rust-lld: error: duplicate symbol: expl
          >>> defined at math_stubs_long_double.cc
          >>>            math_stubs_long_double.o:(expl) in archive /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libstdc++.a
          >>> defined at expl.c
          >>>            lib_a-expl.o:(.text.expl+0x0) in archive /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libm.a

          rust-lld: error: duplicate symbol: fabsl
          >>> defined at math_stubs_long_double.cc
          >>>            math_stubs_long_double.o:(fabsl) in archive /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libstdc++.a
          >>> defined at fabsl.c
          >>>            lib_a-fabsl.o:(.text.fabsl+0x0) in archive /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libm.a

          rust-lld: error: duplicate symbol: floorl
          >>> defined at math_stubs_long_double.cc
          >>>            math_stubs_long_double.o:(floorl) in archive /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libstdc++.a
          >>> defined at floorl.c
          >>>            lib_a-floorl.o:(.text.floorl+0x0) in archive /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libm.a

          rust-lld: error: duplicate symbol: fmodl
          >>> defined at math_stubs_long_double.cc
          >>>            math_stubs_long_double.o:(fmodl) in archive /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libstdc++.a
          >>> defined at fmodl.c
          >>>            lib_a-fmodl.o:(.text.fmodl+0x0) in archive /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libm.a

          rust-lld: error: duplicate symbol: frexpl
          >>> defined at math_stubs_long_double.cc
          >>>            math_stubs_long_double.o:(frexpl) in archive /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libstdc++.a
          >>> defined at frexpl.c
          >>>            lib_a-frexpl.o:(.text.frexpl+0x0) in archive /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libm.a

          rust-lld: error: duplicate symbol: hypotl
          >>> defined at math_stubs_long_double.cc
          >>>            math_stubs_long_double.o:(hypotl) in archive /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libstdc++.a
          >>> defined at hypotl.c
          >>>            lib_a-hypotl.o:(.text.hypotl+0x0) in archive /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libm.a

          rust-lld: error: duplicate symbol: ldexpl
          >>> defined at math_stubs_long_double.cc
          >>>            math_stubs_long_double.o:(ldexpl) in archive /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libstdc++.a
          >>> defined at ldexpl.c
          >>>            lib_a-ldexpl.o:(.text.ldexpl+0x0) in archive /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libm.a

          rust-lld: error: duplicate symbol: log10l
          >>> defined at math_stubs_long_double.cc
          >>>            math_stubs_long_double.o:(log10l) in archive /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libstdc++.a
          >>> defined at log10l.c
          >>>            lib_a-log10l.o:(.text.log10l+0x0) in archive /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libm.a

          rust-lld: error: duplicate symbol: logl
          >>> defined at math_stubs_long_double.cc
          >>>            math_stubs_long_double.o:(logl) in archive /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libstdc++.a
          >>> defined at logl.c
          >>>            lib_a-logl.o:(.text.logl+0x0) in archive /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libm.a

          rust-lld: error: duplicate symbol: modfl
          >>> defined at math_stubs_long_double.cc
          >>>            math_stubs_long_double.o:(modfl) in archive /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libstdc++.a
          >>> defined at modfl.c
          >>>            lib_a-modfl.o:(.text.modfl+0x0) in archive /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libm.a

          rust-lld: error: duplicate symbol: powl
          >>> defined at math_stubs_long_double.cc
          >>>            math_stubs_long_double.o:(powl) in archive /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libstdc++.a
          >>> defined at powl.c
          >>>            lib_a-powl.o:(.text.powl+0x0) in archive /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libm.a

          rust-lld: error: duplicate symbol: copysign
          >>> defined at s_copysign.c
          >>>            lib_a-s_copysign.o:(copysign) in archive /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a
          >>> defined at s_copysign.c
          >>>            lib_a-s_copysign.o:(.text.copysign+0x0) in archive /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libm.a

          rust-lld: error: too many errors emitted, stopping now (use -error-limit=0 to see all errors)


error: aborting due to previous error

error: Could not compile `Monolith`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```